# what's the workflow of style-loader and css-loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm new to webpack, still a little bit confused that how webpack cooperate with loaders. Let's we have below typescript file `index.ts`:

```
//index.ts

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

...
// typescript code
```

and below is the webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: { filename: "bundle.js" },
    resolve: { extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".css"] },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts/, use: "ts-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] }
        ]
    }
};
```

Below is my personal thought on how webpack works with loaders, please correct me if I'm wrong:

Step 1-Webpack encounter `index.ts`, so it passes this file to `ts-loader`, and `ts-loader` read the file and pass it to ts compiler, ts compiler generates js code file `index.js` and pass back to `ts-loader`, then `ts-loader` passes `index.js` back to webpack.

Step 2- Webpack reads `index.js` and needs to resolve the css file, so Webpack passes the task to `css-loader`, so `css-loader` reads the css file as a long long string, then passes the task to `style-loader`, which creates js code that can be embedded in  tags in the index.html file.

Step 3- `bundle.js` is ready, and client sends a http request to get `index.html`, and the `bundle.js` is fetched and create a <style> tags to include all css styles.

Is my above understanding correct? If yes, below is my questions:

Q1-after `style-loader` generates js code, does it pass those js code back to `css-loader`, then `css-loader` passes received js code to webpack? or `style-loader` pass generated js code to webpack directly?

Q2- in the webpack config file:

```
...
{ test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] }
...
```

it seems that the `style-loader` is used first, then `css-loader` steps in( I have tried this approach, it worked, not sure why it worked)

isn't that the `css-loader` should start to work first then `style-loader` as:

```
...
{ test: /\.css$/, use: ["css-loader", "style-loader"] }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my above understanding correct?

Yes

> Q1-after style-loader generates js code, does it pass those js code back to css-loader, then css-loader passes received js code to webpack? or style-loader pass generated js code to webpack directly?

Answer: style-loader pass generated js code to webpack directly

> Q2 it seems that the style-loader is used first, then css-loader steps in,

It can seem wrong. But its one of those things you need to read the docs for. The last thing to process it is mentioned at the top of the array. Personally I don't think the other way around would be any more intuitive.

Comment: so you mean the last loader element in the array will be invoked first to process? that's really weird, is any reason behind it? I didn't see the docs mentions this, could you show me please?

Comment: You can also view it as a dependency tree e.g. `.css` files need `styles-loader` which needs `css-loader`. Its just different ways of looking at it. Loader docs are here : https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders and its correct that its not mentioned in the docs 